# Issue when try to load an eform in the browser

Tags: forms, transform

Hello I am seeing this error when trying to load an e-form in the browser. This is an older form so not sure if the code needs changed or not.

Error: com.imagenow.apiserver.exception.FormTransformFailedException: Failed to load form.

Code sample.

```
<input type="text" id="txtReqAccountId" name="txtReqAccountId" style="width:300px;text-          transform:uppercase;" onblur="getUserInfo(this);">
<xsl:attribute name="value">
<xsl:value-of select="ReqAccountId"/>
</xsl:attribute>                                    
</input>            
</div>
<div class="label" style="text-align:center;">My University Computing Account</div>                         
</td>
```

I had already updated the form to UTF-8